# Push Sales Cloud Event- EventRelation Object data to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, marketing-cloud-connect

Can you please guide.

I am trying to invoke a journey and flow through 4 weeks process of sending email and tracking click etc. The trigger for the journey is from Event and invitees (i.e. Event and Event Relation objects) in Sales Cloud.

1. There is no report type that I can build in Salesforce to find target records and move to DE. There is existing limitation around who can access the meeting and invitees data.
2. I tried configure Data Entry source but it does not move forward after selecting object as "Event".

Is there any other way to fire journey from Sales Cloud for the target meetings ? I am trying to avoid fire event api.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a [custom report type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm&type=5) and include those objects if those were not available in your standard report. You would need to have a contact lookup ID either on event or invitees depending upon your requirement.

You can also try to use Journey builder salesforce entry if you have a look up to contact / lead with events or invitees.

If all the above doesn't satisfy your condition, then you would need to handle the logic in Marketing cloud only. You can sync all the necessary objects like Event and Invitees from sales cloud to marketing cloud using MC connect.

Reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_jb_sync_object.htm&type=5

Once you sync it a data extension will get created under syncronized folder.

Post that you can use SQL query to connect the dots (Event & Invitees) using [JOIN function](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-data-management/query-data-with-sql) and create a resultant data extension. You can schedule it, if you want to do a recurring email.

You can use this data extension as a source to journey builder or automation studio.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hey Naveen, thanks for inputs, realised i could build report on Activities with Contact to find the target records ....

Comment: That's great! @PrashantPatel